# How to dynamic change the size of the icon marker when using Leaflet maps and views

Tags: javascript

I am using the module [Leaflet](https://www.drupal.org/project/leaflet) and its sub-module "[Leaflet views](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/leaflet/tree/leaflet_views)" and [IP Geolocation Views & Maps](https://www.drupal.org/project/ip_geoloc) (IPGV&M for short), which provides a nice way to assign icon images to, in my case, content type in order to get a map displaying markers. I have set it up so to show different markers depending on the content type. I have also a field linked to the nodes, displaying a number, which is the number of users subscribed to that node.

What I need is to **change dynamically the size of the marker**, so that the nodes with more people subscribed (bigger int) will appear bigger than others with lower number.

I am using a view to display the map and the markers.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Leaflet Extension module "[Leaflet Label](https://www.drupal.org/project/leaflet_label)" helps to implement what you are trying to do? It provides a light-weight alternative to marker popups for Leaflet maps using labels, provided by the [Leaflet Label](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.label) javascript plugin.